# Pass ID of Entity via Ajax to Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, parameter-passing

What is the best way to pass the identifier of an object via ajax to the Server / Controller (e.g. we are on the site "book/edit/mybookname" and what to update this book entity "mybookname"  via ajax) ?

I thought of some approaches and wanted to know, what the most common and most secure way would be:

1) Pass the ID of the book to the controller

-> Problem: ID Variable / Field can be changed by using the console of a browser

2) Pass the current URL (window.location.href) to the controller and extract the name out of the url in the controller

-> window.location.href can't be changed through the console ..?

I know that I have to check on server side, if the User should have access to edit the entity. But if he has more than one book, he could possibly change the id parameter to another book that he owns and then he would change another book presentation in the background, not the one he is currently browsing.

Comment: You could set a session variable when the user accesses `book/edit/mybookname`. But I don't really see the point, if a user wants to mess up his / her own collection, that is their problem IMO.

Comment: Hi jeroen, Session variable would not help, you can open several tabs with different books. Ok so the common way is to say: Check access rights,  but when the logged user tries to manipulate the forms / parameters, in the end he can only mess up his books.

Comment: The only way to make sure it cannot be manipulated, is to use a value that does not come from the user but is stored on the server. But as you noticed, that can also fail. So yes, their collection, their problem as long as they only have access to their own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thought ajax you can use post data. That can not be edited in the browser address bar.

```
var xmlhttp;    
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
  {
         //do whatever with response
  }

  };
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax/ajax.php);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("field1=whatever&field2=whateverelse");
```

Comment: Hey kay, thanks for your answer. I think that this would just "move" the possibility of changing the value to another point .. because the problem is not the "passing part", the problem is that I need to store somewhere on the page the id and this value can be changed (In a js config object or a hidden field). So it does not change anything using POST or the URL to transfer the ID. And my conclusion is now that I just pass the "window.location.href", because this value can't get changed.